# Check the Authorization HTTP Header of incoming request, Django

Tags: python, django, validation, request

I should check the Authorization HTTP Header of every incoming request. In case of missing or invalid Authorization header.
How to make simple authorization header validation?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the best way and think it's ugly. Nonetheless, here's my solution:

```
# i did this in views.py
class SomeView(View):
   def get(self, request):
      for key, value in request.header.items():
         # loop through the header...
```

Comment: The point is, "Authorization" header is not printed, even though I have it in the 'networks' (devtools) on the website

Answer (score 0):

In case your token is set to something like this:

```
Token <HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN>
```

you could do something like that:

```
s, token = request.META["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"].split(" ")
```

This gets the authorization header and seperates it into two strings.